# How to read several columns with similar name with pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm reading a csv file with pandas and the file has several columns with similar names, such as column1, column2,..., column50. Is there a way to tell pandas to read these columns (there are others I don't need) without having to type all of them manually to usecols=['column1','column2',...etc.]?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just create that as

```py
..., usecols = [f'column{i}' for i in range(1,51)]
```

this creates a list of strings with values column1, ..., column50

Comment: one could also use a callable not to hardcode column names: `usecols=lambda s: s.startswith('column')` , see https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html#pandas-read-csv